# Having an option to indicate suggested edit queue is full before editing

Tags: feature-request

Is it worth editing the answers and questions when reviewing?

The suggested edits queue is always full and there is no indication if it is full until the point that pressing the submit button.

Can we have a tool-tip or a label to indicate the suggested edit queue is full before start to edit?

Sometimes it feels totally worthless the time spent when it cannot submit the edit!

Comment: Hard to implement. Server checks the queue size, finds that there's room, and lets you in to suggest an edit. Meanwhile Bob submits a suggested edit and fills the queue. Your edit is rejected because the queue's now full. OK, so say we test and then reserve a space in the queue for your future edit. Unfortunately you get called away and commit the edit hours later or never commit the edit. That's a book-keeping nightmare on the server.

Comment: Yep, I understand. But say the queue limit is 1000 and when I start to edit there are 750 already full. So I have a chance of 250 to get a place in the queue. But if it is significantly low like 50 or 20 then the probability of me not going to get into the queue is very low.
Maybe a notice saying "Only 20 slots left" or "Edit queue is nearly full"?

Comment: I think the only real way to clean the edit review queue is to make edits to *cost* 1-2 rep points instead of granting 2. Would make one to think twice about updating capitalization of "thank you" notes...

Comment: *"Sometimes it feels totally worthless the time spent when it cannot submit the edit!"* - it is the burden of not having 2k reputation points yet. If it really does impact you so much, consider suggesting less edits. The main priority is to not burn out and get upset with the site. Making a suggestion like this even when it is received with open arms will not help you in either the short term or the long term because it won't be implemented anytime soon. So switch tactics - do what you must to not be frustrated.